# Symfony 2.3 form checkbox issue

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I have made an form with checkbox in Symfony2.1.13

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($AdvertMst)

        ->add('target', 'checkbox', array('required'  => false, 'attr' => array('check'=>false)))
        ->getForm();
```

it is working fine

but the same thing i am using in Symfony 2.3.* the exception of boolean to string is coming.
I am not able to understand what is role of Data transfer here. Is there any change have been made in version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the array passed to `'attr'` actually get put as attributes. So if you'd like the field to be checked I think you need:

```
->add('target', 'checkbox', array('required'  => false, 'attr' => array('checked'=>'checked'))
```

And if you DO NOT want it checked you can pass an empty string

```
->add('target', 'checkbox', array('required'  => false, 'attr' => array('checked'=>''))
```